# WPF 4: What happened to DataGridColumnHeader?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0, datagridcolumnheader

What happened to DataGridColumnHeader? It looks like it was dropped when the DataGrid was moved into PresentationFramework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`DataGridColumnHeader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.datagridcolumnheader(VS.100).aspx) is under the [`System.Windows.Controls.Primitives`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives(VS.100).aspx) namespace in the `PresentationFramework.dll` assembly.

Comment: Oh, they changed the namespace to System. I wonder why I didn't see that before.

Comment: @Jonathan: Sometimes it's hard to see the wood for the trees. Glad I could help.

Comment: How do you reference it in XAML?

Comment: @Tom: Same as any other type, include its namespace and then reference it via that. Is there a specific scenario where this isn't working?

Comment: MSDN doesn't show a namespace in the xaml example.

Tried xmlns:prim="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=PresentationFramework", doesn't work.

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                    <Grid>
                        <prim:DataGridHeaderBorder ...

The only way I can get it to compile is by cheating and using the WPFToolkit xmlns.

Comment: Perhaps I should make a new question so I can format my text :)

Comment: Did you make sure you have a reference to the DLL? It's working for me, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365350/wpf4-datagridheaderborder-in-a-xaml-style

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column Name" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: DataGridColumnHeader was used for custom styling across all headers.

Comment: Yeah, that's all in WPF styles. What's your specific problem?