# WPF4 DataGridHeaderBorder in a xaml Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0, datagridheaderborder

Making a separate question, related to comments on the answer to [WPF 4: What happened to DataGridColumnHeader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481946/wpf-4-what-happened-to-datagridcolumnheader)

It appears I can use DataGridHeaderBorder in a UserControl, stand-alone in a ResourceDictionary, but not in a Style's setter of a Template.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    >

    <!-- Works -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="yomama">
        <DataGridColumnHeader />
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- Compile Error: error MC3074: The tag 'DataGridHeaderBorder' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'. -->
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}"
        TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                    <Grid>
                        <DataGridHeaderBorder></DataGridHeaderBorder>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I can get it to work if I use xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit", even though I'm not referencing WPFToolkit in the project.  I've verified I'm set to .NET4 and referencing PresentationFramework v4.

Thanks for helping me remove the dg: hack.

Comment: Submitted to MS: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/584894  Vote up if you get a chance

Comment: @Tom. This works for me if I with     
    xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"

HTH

Comment: @Berryl, thanks, but I shouldn't need to reference PresentationFramework.Aero, should I?

Comment: Heck no!! But it seemed marginally less obscure that a toolkit reference that doesn't exist. BTW, when I went to up vote the bug, the link you posted gives a most unhelpful error if you aren't registered for connect, even if MSFT otherwise knows who you are (minor PITA). Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the Themes solution, for some reason the dg: thing isn't working on my laptop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `PresentationFramework.Aero` to your project's references as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this.In this case to change the foreground of the header.

```
<Style x:Key="Consulta_Grilla_HeaderStyle" 
       TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}" >
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>      
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add PresentationFramework.Aero.dll in reference of your project.