# Where is DataGridHeaderBorder for WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, datagridheaderborder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF4 DataGridHeaderBorder in a xaml Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365350/wpf4-datagridheaderborder-in-a-xaml-style)

I found some styles for WPF DataGrid online and all of them are for pre-release DataGrid. Now, I'm using .NET4 DataGrid, I got a compile error complaining DataGridHeaderBorder cannot be found. Based on Microsoft, it is in Microsoft.Windows.Themes namespace. No matter what I try, I can't make it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be bug in .NET4 according to [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/584894/wpf4-datagridheaderborder-in-a-xaml-style). There is also a workaround. Just add a namespace reference like this:

```
xmlns:dg="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">
```

You may have to manually add a reference to `PresentationFramework.Aero` in your project.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this.. (in this case to change the foreground of the hearder)

```
<Style x:Key="Consulta_Grilla_HeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"  >
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}" >
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>      
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Comment: Why do you add a copy of your answer to a question which has been closed as a duplicate of that question you answered before?