# DataGridHeaderBorder missing in System.Windows.Controls

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit, datagridheaderborder

Recently i moved my project from .Net3.5 to .Net4. In earlier version to use DataGrid, i was using `wpfToolkit` and its working fine. But after moving to .Net4 i don't want to explicitly add the refernce to my toolkit since DataGrid has been moved under Controls namespace.

But, all the related references have been moved except for the `DataGridHeaderBorder` under Controls namespace. To use this we have to explicitly ad reference to `PresentationFramework.Aero`. I referred to these URL's -

[WPF4 DataGridHeaderBorder in a xaml Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365350/wpf4-datagridheaderborder-in-a-xaml-style)

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/584894/wpf4-datagridheaderborder-in-a-xaml-style

But i can't add the PresentationFramework.Aero to our project since Aero theme may not be present for all the target environments. So, is there any workaround i can try to get it working? Any how can i get the code from assembly PresentationFramework.Aero for DataGridHeaderBorder so that i can override or subclass it in my code. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could download latest [source code](http://wpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/40156) of `WPFToolkit` and extract `DataGridHeaderBorder` styles from it.

It has `DataGrid\Microsoft\Windows\Controls\DataGridHeaderBorder.cs` and corresponding `Aero`, `Classic`, `Luna` themes in `DataGrid\Themes\*` too.

Comment: Thanks. I created my own class for DataGridHeaderBorder. Since not using any theme in my project, overriding a class works for me.